the latest current/previous week available in DAX
how to leverage the code below based on the expected answer, using lastnonblankvalue,Hasonevalue or something relevant rather then MAX()? many thanks in adcance.
   Current Week Amt = 
    VAR CurrentFiscalWeek = MAX( 'DF'[Fiscal Week num] )
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
         [Amt],
        'DF'[Fiscal Week num] = CurrentFiscalWeek
    )

Previous Week Amt = 
VAR CurrentFiscalWeek = MAX( 'DF'[Fiscal Week num] )
VAR PreviousFiscalWeek = CurrentFiscalWeek - 1
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Amt],
    'DF'[Fiscal Week num] = PreviousFiscalWeek
)

Sample Dataset
Source    Fiscal Week num    Current Week Amt
    Company A       52          5
    Company A       51          10 
    Company A       50          20
    Company B       50          1
    Company B       48          2
    Company B       47          3

What I am getting
  Source      Cur/Pre Week    Amt
    Company A       52          5
    Company A       51          10 
    Company B       52          0
    Company B       51          0

Expected Answer
  Source      Cur/Pre Week    Amt
    Company A       52          5
    Company A       51          10 
    Company B       50          1
    Company B       48          2


How about this?

Amt = 
VAR i = VALUES('Table'[Source])
VAR j = VALUES('Table'[Fiscal Week num])
VAR t = 
    TOPN(2,
    CALCULATETABLE('Table', REMOVEFILTERS(), i),
    'Table'[Fiscal Week num], DESC) 


RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Current Week Amt]),t , j)


I would try using `OFFSET.
Previous Week Amt =
CALCULATE (
    [Amt],
    OFFSET (
        -1,
        ORDERBY (
            'DF'[Fiscal year], ASC,
            'DF'[Fiscal Week num], ASC
        )
    )
)

